# Unknown extra positional argument for function that is being passed into scipy.optimize.minimze

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm supposed to make a script that creates a model for detecting two stimuli, A and B,  with parameters of the value of stimuli A and B (really, a value denoting the prediction of A and B occurring), learning rate for both stimuli, the number of trials to simulate.

But I'm stuck with scipy.optimize.minimize. I think what's most important here regardless of the description of this model/simulation is that the error message I'm getting just seems to be saying that the function I'm trying to pass into minimize has too many positional arguments. I get

```
TypeError: rw_simulation() takes 5 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

The tuple that I'm passing into the args parameter for scipy.optimize.minimize clearly has 5 elements. The learning rates should be floats, the v_stimulus values should be floats as well... the trial_total is supposed to be an int. Something's just not right here about how I'm trying to use minimize, but this error message claiming that there's 6 positional arguments doesn't really help me understand what I can fix.

```
def rw_simulation(v_stimulusA, v_stimulusB, learning_rateA, learning_rateB, trial_total): 
   # this code for the most part isn't important

    reinforcement_val = 100
    stimA_predict_vals = []
    stimB_predict_vals = []
    stimA_predict_vals.append(v_stimulusA)
    stimB_predict_vals.append(v_stimulusB)

    for trial in range(trial_count):
        # unimportant computation
        v_stimulusA += learning_rateA*(reinforcement_val - delta_diff)
        v_stimulusB += learning_rateB*(reinforcement_val - delta_diff)
        stimA_predict_vals.append(v_stimulusA) # stores the change in value for stimA at the end of each trial.
        stimB_predict_vals.append(v_stimulusB) # also stores the change in value for stimB at the end of each trial
    return stimA_predict_vals, stimB_predict_vals

trial_count = 200
start_predictA = 0
start_predictB = 0
learning_rateA = 0.3
learning_rateB = 0.3
hw1_data = np.load("hw1_data.npy") # np array containing initial guesses, though it is possible that this var is causing problems. However, the error message at hand clearly isn't related to this.
stimulus_prediction_vals_tuple = ()
stimulus_prediction_vals_tuple = rw_simulation(start_predictA, start_predictB, learning_rateA, learning_rateB, trial_count)

minimize(rw_simulation, hw1_data, args=(start_predictA, start_predictB, learning_rateA, learning_rateB, trial_count,), method='nelder-mead')
```

I just want to at least resolve this error message concerning the extra positional arguments for now. I actually have some concerns that the "hw1_data" argument, which I'm using for the x0 parameter of scipy.optimize.minimize, might not be the variable I'm supposed to be using. But if that were causing this error message... It's obviously not apparent at all. Plus I'll leave that for another question.

Really, how am I passing in 6 positional arguments? Where is the 6th one coming from?

Edit: at some point when I took out the args paramter or set the tuple to be ()/empty, I got an error message that basically said that every argument other than the first parameter of my rw_simulation function WASN'T being set. So something's being passed into that first parameter it seems, and that's causing the extra argument.
I have literally no clue what that first parameter is or could be coming from though. Maybe the function name? But... then what am I supposed to do?

Comment: `minimize` passes the `x0` variable (the one it varies) plus the `args` tuple (all joined into one tuple).  `(x0,)+args` is 6 items long.  `minimize` assumes you want it to be varying the first argument to `rw_simulation`.

Comment: Alright. Well, I'm actually trying to vary both the learning_rate argument and the reinforcement_val argument in order to find their optimal values. How would you be able to pass in multiple variables for minimize to estimate/vary? (Using a list including both variables for x0 is not working, the list is accepted as one argument and not multiple)

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed that those arguments were the minimization ones; you didn't give any indication to `minimize` to that effect, did you?  And do these values have any connection with `hw1_data`?  You don't describe that.

Comment: Reread what the `minimize` docs say about `fun`: `Must be in the form f(x, *args).`, where `x` is the `optimization argument` (it may be a 1d array)

Comment: I'm baffled that you expected it to optimize `reinforcement_val`, considering that `reinforcement_val` isn't even an argument to the function at all. Changing `reinforcement_val` would be changing the objective function itself.

Comment: Someone could delete this question. basically the code I posted here was different from an edit I made not long after making this post and I did include reinforcement_val as an argument. Basically, I didn't understand that for minimize(), the function you pass in needs to have the values its trying to estimate/minimize as arguments to that function and that all of these values will get estimated. If that's how I quite remember it at the moment. I just wasn't sure of that from the documentation. I could provide the code for it later.